# "Leader board" vs. "leaderboard"

Tags: nouns, orthography, spacing

Is there a preferred spelling for the word "leaderboard"? Should it be one word or two? It would seem that both are correct, but is either preferred?

Comment: If you are referring to "leaderboard ads" (780 X 90 pixels), I've only ever seen it spelled as one word. (Google *leaderboard ad*.)

Comment: I wasn't but that is interesting. I was thinking of a board with leaders on it.

Comment: Whichever way the [PGA](http://www.pgatour.com/leaderboard.html) spells it.

Comment: Do you prefer AHD or Collins? CED or Lexico? USA TODAY or the Houston Chronicle? Forbes or the Sunday Times? PC Mag or The Sun?

Answer (score 3):

If I look up *leaderboard* as one word in OED, it returns a reference to *leader board* as two words, which I suppose says something about which they think is correct!

Searching the corpora yields 13 instances without a space in the British National Corpus (BNC) against nine with a space; and in the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA) it's 82 without versus 90 with. [I think; I'm not all that familiar with those tools]

I would say those results are inconclusive.

Comment: What does the term mean? A Google search suggests that it's "leaderboard" and just a list of the top ten or twenty players in a golf tournament. But if you go to some of the sites, they spell it "Leader Board". I'd say that there is no _correct_ spelling. Just pretend it's _loose_ for _lose_ and _it's_ for _its_ and you'll be fine: IOW, accept what you see and spell it as you like and no one will be the wiser, nor will anyone be able to complain that you've spelled it incorrectly. As a kicker, you can always claim that Jane Austen spelled it the way you do. That usually does the trick.

Comment: That's certainly the usage in the corpora.

Comment: [This site](http://hosted.stats.com/golffront.asp?tour=PGA) uses one word, FWIW.

Comment: Inconclusive? 82 - 90 seems a reasonable sample, so I'd say 'spelling variant optional' rather than 'results inconclusive'.

Answer (score 2):

## A board by any other name:

It's really no different than blackboard. Inevitably, "leaderboard" will become increasingly more formally accepted.

## If in doubt:

If in doubt, I'd hyphenate the two words:

> leader-board

...or...

> Leader-Board

## Purpose of one-word usage:

From the usage I've seen online, the advantage of the one-word variant is **concision** when used as a (or part of a) title.

E.g.

1. URL structures: www.test.com/leaderboard
2. Link text: My Leaderboard
3. Title: Masters Tournament Leaderboard